# mingw 5 std::this_thread not defined

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, c++14

Hi any body try to use  header support mingw w64?

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:9:10: error: 'std::this_thread' has not been declared
std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );
      ^
```

I got above error with following simple test

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono> 
#include <thread>

int main()
{ 
 std::cout << "Hello waiter" << std::endl;
 std::chrono::milliseconds dura( 2000 );
 std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );
 std::cout << "Waited 2000 ms\n";
}
```

I want to use lastest N3653 and N3651 as spesified here https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html and of course threading support header , using someone builds found here http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/dongsheng-daily/5.0/
 and my c++config.h _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP is not defined , any idea?

[EDIT]
I realize that my thread model was: win32 and not posix one. How to enable posix support?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71790/discussion-on-question-by-user3453753-mingw-5-stdthis-thread-not-defined).

Answer (score 0):

You can use update-alternatives for `i686-w64-mingw-g++` and set it to `i686-w64-mingw-g++-posix` from `i686-w64-mingw-g++-win32`.

Or you can just use `i686-w64-mingw-g++-posix` to compile.
There are other versions so in this case you'd use the 64 bit compiler instead and append the `-posix` to it.